# Unity WebGL: can I access to MySql using MySqlConnector?

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a WebGL app with Unity 2018.

I need to access a MySQL database hosted on the same server.

My questions is: can I use C# and MySqlConnector (solution i prefer),  or I have to use instead web services calls ?

EDIT: it seems it's not either possible to use/consume web service in WebGL build, because System.Web.Services it's not accessible.

Thanks

Comment: maybe this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-and-mysql.376556/) can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general way for doing this (both for security reasons and it's just all round a more standard way from the unity side of things) is that you simply host the server side database interaction pages within php and then make use of either the [WWW or UnitWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html) classes to actually utilize this.

You can fairly easily get back Json formatted data to work with on the client side

A fairly old (though still kinda relevant) tutorial/guide for something along these lines can be found [Here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores)

Generally, the idea is though - Game makes a request to PHP using an encrypted key of some kind for validation, PHP does the database work and then fires back some data usually in Json format

Comment: my database has local and i want to communicate with database without php and directly from unity and c#. i used MysqlClient and mysqlConnector/.Net but it doesn't support webgl. i am making a local application and security doesn't matter to me. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a websocket. The server who will host the WebGL app will have a websocket server, who will do the MySQL communication and return the results. And the WebGL app(the unity one) connects to this websocket using a Auth Token(To ensure that is the WebGL connecting, not someone else) and get the results from the queries there

Answer (score 1):

You might already have your answer but i have done it few weeks ago and its pretty easy.
I am posting both php and c# code below, have a look:

**C# Code**

```
 WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
WWW www = new WWW("url of file location on server goes here", form);
yield return www;
Debug.Log(www.text);// this should return "successful connection"
```

**PHP Code**

replace '123' with required fields

```
 <?php
$servername = "123";
$server_username = "123";
$server_password = "123";
$dbName = "123"; 

//Connection
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbName", $server_username, $server_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed.");
}else{
echo "Connection Successful";
} 
?>
```

Hope its helps!